# What is the fastest possible solution for concurent read/write into hash-maps?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, hashmap, network-programming

I am writing a network service which receives raw packets then converts them and puts them into a queue, there are also a couple of worker threads that take the converted packets from the queue and based on some rules update a hash-map. in order to prevent concurrent update on hash-map from different worker threads I have to use mutex. unfortunately using mutex imposes a big performance hit. I need to find a work around for this.

EDITED:
the converted packets contain a **sessio_id**, this session_id is used as the hash-map **key**.  Before any insertion or update the session_id is first **searched** and if there is no session_id found then a new entry is **added** and **this is exactly where i use mutex lock**, otherwise if the session_id already exists I just **update** the existing value and there is no mutex lock used for mere value update. It might be helping to know that I use **boost::unordered_map** as the underlying hash-map.

below is a psudo code of the logic I use:

```
   if hash.find(session_id) then
      hash.update(value)
   else
      mutex.lock()
      hash.insert(value)
      mutex.unlock()
   end
```

what is you suggestion?

by the way this is my working environment and tools:

Compiler: C++(gcc)

Thread library: pthread

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I think you need to add how often you read from the hashmap, how often you update the hashmap and how many readers of the hashmap you have got.

Comment: @SergeiKurenkov I added some details :)

Comment: I think you have got an error here: `otherwise if the session_id already exists I just update the existing value and there is no mutex lock used for mere value update`. Adding a new key can cause the hashmap to reallocate memory inside and accessing a key at the same time in another thread surely must lead to error.

Comment: You can't search the map outside the mutex while other threads are inserting things.

Comment: By the way I don't see exact figures for reads/second, writes/second and the number of readers in your updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

The fastest solution would be to split the data in a way that each thread uses its own data set, so you would not need any locking at all. Maybe you can get there by distributing the messages among the threads based on some key data.

Second best solution would be to have a read-write-spinlock implemented using either C++ 11 atomics or the functions from the C library, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.0/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html
Read-write spinlock typically allow multiple, parallel read accesses, but only one write access (which of course also blocks all read accesses).

There is also a read-write mutex in Linux, but I found it to be slightly slower than a hand-made implementation.

Comment: +1 I like the idea of associating a session ID with a thread to avoid locking completely, but you need a mechanism to pass reads and writes to a particular thread based on the ID, Also searching without ID is more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into lock-free data structures? You can refer to an interesting paper from Andrei Alexandrescu and Maged Michael, [Lock-Free Data Structures with Hazard Pointers](http://erdani.com/publications/cuj-2004-12.pdf). Some implementations using similar ideas can for instance be found on the [libcds](https://github.com/khizmax/libcds) Github repository.

Although they use locking to some extent, Facebook's [folly AtomiHashMap](https://github.com/facebook/folly) and Intel's [TBB](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) also provide high performance concurrent hash-maps.

Of course these approaches will require a bit a extra reading and integration work, but if you have determined that your current locking strategy is the bottleneck, it may well be worth the cost.